# how can install SYNTENYMINER for visualization of genome alginment?

Tags: installation, apt

I want to install SYNTENYMINER on ubuntu 12.04

```
marwa@marwa-Vostro-1540:~$ cd Desktop/SYNTENYMINER
marwa@marwa-Vostro-1540:~/Desktop/SYNTENYMINER$ `sudo apt-get install SYNTENMINER`
[sudo] password for marwa:  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done E:
Unable to locate package SYNTENMINER
marwa@marwa-Vostro-1540:~/Desktop/SYNTENYMINER$ `sudo gedit etc/apt/sources.list`
```

i found the gedit was empty so how can i install it ?? and what these previous line mean????

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to install a application in tar.gz format from source-code with `apt-get`?

This type format is not installed with `apt-get`.

To install applications in the tar.gz format refer to [Compiling Easy How To at - help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

Comment: I'm asking because your changing into a folder on your desktop called SYNTENYMINER which is probably the extracted tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

The above information says that, you tried to install `syntenyminer` from repository with `apt-get install syntenyminer` which does not exist in repo. Thats why terminal give you

> E: Unable to locate package SYNTENMINER

this output.

At last you tried to edit **sources.list** file with **gedit**. It open blank because, there is no such file in your given address. You gave **etc/apt/sources.list** which does not really exist. The correct path of the **sources.list** is `/etc/apt/sources.list`
Then the command will be like this `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

If you don't provide the actual name of the package the `apt-get` can not install your software.

Comment: ok , i go with u step by step , after sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list what is the second step after the gedit appear with alot of deb. lines?????

Comment: Yap, its call repository from where your software center download software and upgrade your system.